# How to Infer generic type from generic argument type of another argument

Tags: c#, generics

*MVC has nothing to do with my problem. Don't get confused for the example. Its a pure C# problem*

*The title of the question is not well explaining the question I think.*

---

Suppose, I have a base class for some entity classes called `EntityBase`

Some classes are like

```
class Entity1 : EntityBase
class Entity2 : EntityBase
```

I have an abstract Repository that works with basic operations on entities. The declaration is:

```
abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
```

And there are several implementations of this class

```
class Repository1 : RepositoryBase<Entity1>
class Repository2 : RepositoryBase<Entity2>
```

Now there are some controllers with a base:

```
public abstract class RepositoryControllerBase<TRepository, TEntity> 
        where TRepository : RepositoryBase<TEntity>
        where TEntity : EntityBase
```

And implementations are like

```
class Controller1 : RepositoryControllerBase<Repository1, Entity1>
class Controller2 : RepositoryControllerBase<Repository2, Entity2>
```

Now, you must have noticed that, When the type of repository in a controller is `Repository1`, The entity type must be `Entity1`. Otherwise it will be a compilation error.

So, I think there is a way to skip the second generic type and automatically infer that one. I just do not know how. Any suggestions?

Perhaps, the problem could be easily solved with `?` if it was Java. Replacing ControllerBase declaration with

```
public abstract class RepositoryControllerBase<TRepository> 
            where TRepository : RepositoryBase<?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no constraint type inference for a reason: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/03/09/why-not-automatically-infer-constraints.aspx

Also, the obvious counterexample for your idea would be using interfaces:

```
interface IEntity1 : IEntityBase {}
interface IEntity2 : IEntityBase {}

interface IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntityBase {}

class Repository1 : RepositoryBase<IEntity1> {}
class Repository2 : RepositoryBase<IEntity2> {}
class Repository12 : IRepositoryBase<IEntity1>, IRepositoryBase<IEntity2> {}

public abstract class RepositoryControllerBase<TRepository, TEntity> 
    where TRepository : RepositoryBase<TEntity>
    where TEntity : IEntityBase {}

class Controller1 : RepositoryControllerBase<Repository1, Entity1>
class Controller2 : RepositoryControllerBase<Repository2, Entity2>
class Controller12 : RepositoryControllerBase<Repository12, Entity1>
```

Without specifying an `Entity1` type parameter in a `Controller12` definition, what should a compiler check?

Comment: I did not get `class Repository12 : IRepositoryBase<IEntity1>, IRepositoryBase<IEntity2> {}`. I get compilation error trying that. Is this a typo?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you have converted them to interface. Ok, its not typo.

Comment: It seems that Java and C# has handled things in two different way. Java is not supporting `class Repository12 : IRepositoryBase<IEntity1>, IRepositoryBase<IEntity2> {}` and C# not supporting auto inference. For my context, the java solution seems more reasonable.

Comment: @Mohaimin Why? The java solution allows you to write a bit less (by automatically inferring some constraints), but forbids you to do some things which interfere with type inference. C# forces you to write type constraints explicitly, but then allows you to implement more than a single interface.

Comment: I am sorry I am late. I prefer the java one because `Repository12 : IRepositoryBase<IEntity1>, IRepositoryBase<IEntity2> {}` is confusing. What if `IRepositoryBase` contains a method like `TEntity GetEntity()`? I tried this. I could not find a way to invoke `GetEntity()` from `Repository12`

Comment: @Mohaimin `((IRepositoryBase<IEntity2>)this).GetEntity()`?

Comment: :) I knew there must be a way. Just could not find.